# Change the default ValidationRule error behavior of a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, controltemplate

I created a custom `ControlTemplate` for my `TextBoxes` and I can't manage to override the default behaviour of the ValidationRule errors.

The `TextBox` border just turn red and i can't find where to override this.
The thing i'd like to to in my `ControlTemplate` is something like this :

```
<EventSetter Event="HasError" Handler="TextBox_HasErrors"/>
```

And in my code behind :

```
private void TextBox_HasErrors(...)
{
  //Change few things in my TextBox
}
```

As I Overrided the default `ControlTemplate` of the `TextBox`, i have this `ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"` which I think is responsible for the border coloration, but i don't know how and where to change that

Actually my usage of the textBox is like this :

```
<TextBox Tag="Email">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Email" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:TextBoxEmailValidationRule Domain=".com"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Does some one know how i could change the red border behavior ?

Comment: It's set by the attached property Validation.ErrorTemplate. Inside your replacement template you put     <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate> but look up examples. Or explain exactly what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red border is defined in the default `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the control. You can easily create your own error template by setting the attached property to a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBox Tag="Email">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Email" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:TextBoxEmailValidationRule Domain=".com"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) blog post for more information about this and data validation in WPF in general.